# Embedding ruby inside script rails haml file, how?

Tags: javascript, ajax, haml

I have this piece of code which use Ajax to send data to server, how I can     pass argument id in data which is in 'params', something in erb is like

```
id: <%= params[:id] %>
```

But I need it in haml

```
 %script(type="text/javascript")
      function send_data(){
      $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/create_comment',
      data:{
      comment: $('#comment_content').val(),
      parent_type: 'project'
      }
      });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not able to access params directly in javascript.
For that first save this id as instance variable in controllers action.
like

```
@some_id = params[:id]
```

If you are using coffescript then in your haml add following line at
the end

```
:coffeescript
  @some_id = #{@some_id}
```

Now you can access this id directly in your JS

```
data = some_id
```

Thanks